# How to achieve no indentation for a single equation?

Tags: amsmath, indentation

I'd like to have a **single equation without indentation** at all.
I know I can set it globally with

```
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}
```

But I don't know how to return to the default value after the equation.

Here my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Default indentation: 
\begin{equation}
  a+b=42
\end{equation}
%
Now I want no indention for a single equation:
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}
\begin{equation}
  a+b=42
\end{equation}
%
Now I'd like to get the default again:
\begin{equation}
  a+b=42
\end{equation}
%
But how?

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this answer is much better:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167926/73767
It does not affect subsequent equations (even center alignment).  But if you use [fleqn] option the center alignment is lost and the subsequent equations become left aligned with fixed indent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Default indentation: 
\begin{equation}
  a+b=42
\end{equation}
%
Now I want no indention for a single equation:
{\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}
\begin{equation}
  a+b=42
\end{equation}}%
%
Now I'd like to get the default again:
\begin{equation}
  a+b=42
\end{equation}
%
But how?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...even the basic principles are unknown to me. Thanks! I will accept as soon as possible.

Comment: @thewaywewalk almost all tex assignments are _local_ so any settings are lost at the next `}` or `\end{zzz}`

Comment: I think this answer is much better:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167926/73767
It does not affect subsequent equations (even center alignment).  But if you use [fleqn] option the center alignment is lost and the subsequent equations become left aligned with fixed indent.

Comment: I downvoted this answer since it has unfortunate side-effects: it indents the paragraph right after the equation.

Comment: @Matthew you must have copied the code incorrectly. This does not cause any non math text to be indented, I added an image of the output to the answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry I am not very good with Latex, but I can ensure you that with the particular cls I'm using, I get an indentation for "Now I'd like". That being said, you're right this does not happen in the article class, so I have removed the downvote.

Comment: @Matthew that would be a bug in the class file. It happens. Either that or you added a blank  line before `Now`