# equation dotfill between index

Tags: equations

My university's thesis require weird equation style, like (d) below:

[image]

code here:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

equation with dotfill:
\begin{equation}
  (a) 1+1=2 \dotfill
\end{equation}

equation without dotfill:
\begin{equation}
  (b) 1+1=2 
\end{equation}

(c) text without dotfill

(d) text with dotfill \dotfill (index)

\end{document}
```

I get align-left by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167925/how-to-make-maths-equations-start-at-the-left), but I don't how to use \dotfill in equation. (a) have same behavior with (b).

Many thx !

Comment: In a normal `equation` environment there is no problem in using `\dotfill`. Please provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) so that we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Do you sometimes have multi-line equations like an `align`? Also, is this regular, in-text equations, or something that forms part of a List of Equations, like a Table of Contents (for equations)?

Comment: @campa Thx for your suggestion, MWE and picture were uploaded.

Comment: @Werner Yeah, but I don't know the relationship between multi-line equations and this question.

Comment: @J.C.: How about [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/jprx31TP)?

Comment: @Werner Wow, wonderfull !! Seems \makeatletter ..... \makeatother fix this problem perfectly ! I am going to learn something about your solution.